# Determine level of nesting in R?

Tags: r, list, nested

Is there an easy way (i.e. a function) to determine the level of nesting in list?
I know there is `str` which can be used to get this information. But is there something that simply gives back the result? And can I use such a function to get the names of all levels of alist (recursively) ?

Comment: You could try `s <- (capture.output(str(mylist, nest.lev=1))[-1])` and then use string processing to capture the number of `..`s that start each element of `s`. (If I get 10 minutes later and there's no better answer by then, I'll give that a shot myself.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A little recursive function can do this for you:

```
depth <- function(this,thisdepth=0){
  if(!is.list(this)){
    return(thisdepth)
  }else{
    return(max(unlist(lapply(this,depth,thisdepth=thisdepth+1))))    
  }
}
```

If you've got `package:testthat`, here's a test set:

```
l1=list(1,2,3)
l2=list(1,2,l1,4)
l3=list(1,l1,l2,5)

require(testthat)
expect_equal(depth(l1),1)
expect_equal(depth(l2),2)
expect_equal(depth(l3),3)
```

Apologies for using lower-case L in variable names. Readability fail.

Comment: +1 -- A bit shorter would be `depth <- function(this) ifelse(is.list(this), 1L + max(sapply(this, depth)), 0L)`

Comment: Nice improvement! Passes my tests. R Code Golf anyone?

Comment: Thanks guys. Very nice indeed. I am somewhat surprised that there is no base solution for this.

Comment: list() returns -inf, quick fix: if(is.list(this) && length(this) == 0){return(0)}

Answer (score 7):

You can now use `depth()` from the `purrr` package!

**Note:** currently the function is part of the development version of `purrr` but will become part of the official CRAN version once the package gets a version bump

Comment: I think its now in CRAN as  `purrr::vec_depth`, but there's also `plotrix::listDepth`

Comment: `listDepth` was removed from the `plotrix` package in version 3.8-1. But +1 for `purrr::vec_depth`, which gets the job done.

Comment: Update on the function name
`vec_depth()` was deprecated in purrr 1.0.0.
Please use `pluck_depth()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If all elements are named, you could use this (from the code of `unlist`):

```
mylist <- list(a=list(x=1),b=list(c=list(y=c(2,3)),d=c("a","b")))
names(.Internal(unlist(mylist, TRUE, TRUE)))
#[1] "a.x"    "b.c.y1" "b.c.y2" "b.d1"   "b.d2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (extension of base `rapply()`):

```r
library(rrapply)

l1 <- list(1, 2, 3)
l2 <- list(1, 2, l1, 4)
l3 <- list(1, l1, l2, 5)

max(rrapply(l1, f = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos), how = "unlist"))
#> [1] 1
max(rrapply(l2, f = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos), how = "unlist"))
#> [1] 2
max(rrapply(l3, f = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos), how = "unlist"))
#> [1] 3
```