# How to select all elements of a list at a particular nested Level?

Tags: r, list, operators

Or put it differently: How can I use the `[[` operator in a nested list?

You can consider this as a follow-up question on this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432863/determine-level-of-nesting-in-r), when I asked how to determine the depth level of a list. I got some decent answers from @Spacedman and @flodel who both suggested recursive functions. Both solutions where quite similar and worked for me.

However I haven't figured out yet what to do with the information I get from these functions. Let's say I have a list nested at level `i` and I want to get back a list that contains all `i-th` level elements, like this:

```
myList$firstLevel$secondLevel$thirdLevel$fourthLevel
# fourthLevel contains 5 data.frames and thirdLevel has
# three elements
```

How can I get back all 15 data.frames from `mylist`?
I am trying to use e.g.

```
lapply(mylist,"[[",2)
```

but obviously I just get the second element of all list elements at the first level.

EDIT: I found the following in the help of `extract` respectivel `?"[["` but can't really wrap my head around it so far:
`"[[ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single index i is a vector of length p, alist[[i]] is equivalent to alist[[i1]]...[[ip]] providing all but the final indexing results in a list."`

EDIT:
Don't want to end up nesting loops like this.

```
o <- list()
i=1
for (i in 1:2){
o[[i]] <- mylist[[c(i,1,1,1)]]
}
```

Comment: it means `mylist[[ c(1,2) ]]` will get you the second element of the first element of `mylist`.

Comment: Thanks Romain, actually this helps as I could try to determine max values for very level and then loop through them. So the next step would be: How to find length of my list recursively?

Comment: Are you asking for the length at each level, or just the lengths of the lowest-level list elements?

Comment: sorry for being imprecise. I mean the length at each level.

Comment: If at level 4 you had the 15 data.frames you mention plus a nested list, would you like to return just the 15 data.frames or everything all together? In other words, do you only want the leaves at a specific level, or both leaves and branches?

Comment: @flodel: Basically I am trying to understand the whole thing and get a better understanding of recursive functions (in R). In this specific situation I have a moderate number of elements (1-3) on the first levels and 5+ on the last level (which are all data.frames). All I want is to put all of these data.frames into a 1 level named list, which I can bring to an environment later on using list2env at the very end.

Comment: I guess at the moment it would simply help a lot if I knew how to refer to the deepest level when I determined the depth with the help of the function you shown yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in the meantime. Can't say say I did it on my own. This
[link](https://sites.google.com/site/akhilsbehl/geekspace/articles/r/linearize_nested_lists_in_r) gives an elaborate explanation how to use another (complex) recursive function to linearize the whole nested list wad.

What's really nice about the solution provided by Akhil S. Behl: it deals with the fact that data.frames are lists too and recursing can stop before data.frames. It turned out that this was one of my major problems before.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to a similar problem and this question sounded promising.  Sadly, the link to the solution no longer works.  This is why SO discourages use of external links.

Comment: @arielf I am sorry you are right about external link. Guess that was a rookie's mistake. It's been a while but I think I used akhil's code in an old project https://github.com/mbannert/gateveys2 . If so I gave him credit in the comments and his name should be easy to find. Hth