# Check if a list is nested or not

Tags: r, list, nested, nested-lists

Is there a "built-in"/efficient and robust way to check if list objects are nested or not?

To clarify my understanding of the term *nested*:

**Flat or not-nested list**

```
x.1 <- list(
    a=TRUE, 
    b=1:5
)
```

**Nested list**

```
x.2 <- list(
    a=list(a.1=list(a.1.1=TRUE)), 
    b=list(b.1=1:5)
)
```

My first idea was to use a combination of `str`, `capture.output` and regular expressions. But as everything related to regular expression: pretty powerful, pretty risky on the robustness side ;-) So I wondered if there's something better out there:

```
isNested <- function(x) {
    if (class(x) != "list") {
        stop("Expecting 'x' to be a list")
    }
    out <- FALSE
    strout <- capture.output(str(x))
    idx <- grep("\\$.*List", strout)
    if (length(idx)) {
        out <- TRUE
    }
    return(out)
}

> isNested(x=x.1)
[1] FALSE
> isNested(x=x.2)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Second approach courtesy of Roman and Arun:

```
isNested2 <- function(x) {
    if (class(x) != "list") {
        stop("Expecting 'x' to be a list")
    }
    out <- any(sapply(x, is.list))
    return(out)
}

> isNested2(x=x.1)
[1] FALSE
> isNested2(x=x.2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: What if you checked your first order list if class is list? If yes, it's nested, else not. Something along the lines of `any(sapply(x.2, function(x) class(x) == "list"))`. `any(sapply(x.1, function(x) class(x) == "list"))` returns FALSE.

Comment: `any(sapply(my_list, class) == "list")`

Comment: Right, that would have been easier ;-) Thanks guys! Embedded your approach as a second approach. Cheers

Comment: For bonus points (how deeply nested is the list), see @Spacedman's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13433689/1270695

Comment: @Rappster, `any(.)` already provides `TRUE/FALSE`. You don't have to wrap it around an `if-statement (or assign out to FALSE)..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `is.list` function:

```
any(sapply(x.1, is.list))
[1] FALSE

any(sapply(x.2, is.list))
[1] TRUE
```

---

As a function `isNested`:

```
isNested <- function(l) {
  stopifnot(is.list(l))
  for (i in l) {
    if (is.list(i)) return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```

Instead of testing all list elements, the function stops as soon as it detects a nested list.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
   isNested <- function(x) {
    if (is.list(x))
        stop("Expecting 'x' to be a list")

    any(unlist( lapply(x,is.list) ))
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and putting it into "my function context"! Gave it to Sven though because it's just a tiny bit more concise. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way for the fun of it:

```
length(unlist(l, FALSE)) != length(unlist(l))
```

Or a variation on that:

```
!identical(unlist(l, FALSE), unlist(l))
```

Makes use of the `recursive` parameter of `unlist()`. With the error checking as well if you want:

```
isNested <- function(l) {
  if (!is.list(l)) stop("Not a list.")
  !identical(unlist(l, FALSE), unlist(l))  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the contents of the list are S3 objects which in turn have a nested list? I'd want these *not* to be treated as lists, so that a list of these objects is "not nested" (it's just a list of objects rather than a list of lists). Using `class()` rather than `is.list()` so that check if *literally* list rather than something else with an embedded list.

```r
is.nested <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.list(x))
  any(sapply(x, function(x) any(class(x) == "list")))
}
```