# Knitr - stop superscript in R Markdown

Tags: r, format, knitr

I need to stop superscript before comma - `,` or full stop - `.`. When converting the `Rmd` file to HTML knitr makes comma superscripted as well. Example:

**example.Rmd**

```
MyTitle
========================================================
J.Smith^1, K.John^2, H.Gone^*.
```

**example.html**

[image]

Let me know if this was asked before, I can't find relevant questions.

Comment: If you ever plan on running your work through pandoc subsequent to this, I would recommend using something like `J.Smith^1^, K.John^2^.` From "knitr", you can also use the `pandoc(..., format="html")` function to convert the resulting ".md" file to a pandoc-style HTML file instead.

Comment: [Related question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15779737/1270695)... and you edited the question :-)

Comment: Sorry for that! But now we have a pure R Markdown & pure pandoc solutions :)

Comment: @gagolews, sorry for what? Your answer definitely adds to the answer that was already available, so nothing to be sorry about :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may insert HTML tags directly to Markdown documents. To toggle the "superscripting" mode, use `sup`.

```
MyTitle
========================================================

J.Smith<sup>1</sup>, K.John<sup>2</sup>, H.Gone<sup>*</sup>.
```

**EDIT**: You may also use [round brackets](https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/blob/master/src/markdown.c) to indicate exactly the part of text to be reformatted.

```
J.Smith^(1), K.John^(2), H.Gone^(*)
```

**EDIT:** This has changed for [Markdown V2](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html)

```
2^10  
2^(10)  
2^10^  
2^(10)^
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for these options. They are the most direct approaches if you are going to be outputting to HTML. However, neither work very nicely if your final intention is PDF or another format.

Comment: Thanks for comments and answers, final intended output is HTML.