# Markdown code for subscripts and superscripts

Tags: r

I want to display b3* in R Markdown with 3 being a subscript and * being a superscript on the same vertical level?
my code:

```
b*~3~
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757695/producing-subscripts-in-r-markdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Producing subscripts in R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757695/producing-subscripts-in-r-markdown)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$b^*_3$
```

Result after knitting to pdf:

[image]