# R-Markdown subscript in [square brackets]

Tags: r-markdown

This is my R-markdown code:

```
$\mu$Biomass~(Total)~[CO~2~@400ppm]
```

Everything works as it should, except for the subscript for the CO2. I'm guessing it's because it's in the square brackets, yes?

How should I go about getting subscript within square brackets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Producing subscripts in R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757695/producing-subscripts-in-r-markdown)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Well, maybe indirectly. I followed the link to the pandoc manual and found that the backtick wrapper should do what I need... and it did! :D Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping each square bracket with backticks solved my problem:

```
$\mu$Biomass~(Total)~`[`CO~2~ @ 400ppm`]`
```

This now works perfectly!