# Removing elements in a nested R list by name

Tags: r, list

I have a nested element like this

```
> x <- list(a=list(from="me", id="xyz"), b=list(comment=list(list(message="blabla", id="abc"), list(message="humbug", id="jkl"))), id="123")
> str(x)
List of 3
 $ a :List of 2
  ..$ from: chr "me"
  ..$ id  : chr "xyz"
 $ b :List of 1
  ..$ comment:List of 2
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ message: chr "blabla"
  .. .. ..$ id     : chr "abc"
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ message: chr "humbug"
  .. .. ..$ id     : chr "jkl"
 $ id: chr "123"
```

How can I remove all the elements with name `id` in all levels of the list? i.e. the expected output is

```
> str(x)
List of 2
 $ a:List of 1
  ..$ from: chr "me"
 $ b:List of 1
  ..$ comment:List of 2
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ message: chr "blabla"
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ message: chr "humbug"
```

Solutions using `rlist` package would be particularly welcome, but I'm happy with anything that works.

Comment: Can you show expected output? (use `dput` instead of `str`)

Comment: expected output is the second block of quote above

Comment: `dput` is your friend

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recursion is also how I did it:

```
# recursive function to remove name from all levels of list
stripname <- function(x, name) {
    thisdepth <- depth(x)
    if (thisdepth == 0) {
        return(x)
    } else if (length(nameIndex <- which(names(x) == name))) {
        x <- x[-nameIndex]
    }
    return(lapply(x, stripname, name))
}

# function to find depth of a list element
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432863/determine-level-of-nesting-in-r
depth <- function(this, thisdepth=0){
    if (!is.list(this)) {
        return(thisdepth)
    } else{
        return(max(unlist(lapply(this,depth,thisdepth=thisdepth+1))))    
    }
}


str(stripname(x, "id"))
## List of 2
## $ a:List of 1
## ..$ from: chr "me"
## $ b:List of 1
## ..$ comment:List of 2
## .. ..$ :List of 1
## .. ..$ :List of 1
## .. .. ..$ message: chr "blabla"
## .. .. ..$ message: chr "humbug"
```

Comment: You could replace `if (length(nameIndex <- which(names(x) == name)))` by `if (any(nameIndex <- names(x) == name)))` I think

Answer (score 3):

Try a recursive function in the veins of

```
f <- function(i) 
  lapply(i, function(x) 
    if (is.list(x)) { 
      if(!is.null(names(x))) f(x[names(x)!="id"]) else f(x) 
    } else x
  )
str(f(x[names(x)!="id"]))
# List of 2
#  $ a:List of 1
#   ..$ from: chr "me"
#  $ b:List of 1
#   ..$ comment:List of 2
#   .. ..$ :List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ message: chr "blabla"
#   .. ..$ :List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ message: chr "humbug"
```

Comment: This will only work if the depth of the list is 2 as in the example. If there are deeper elements, we need a recursive stuff -- maybe rewrite with `rapply`(didn't succeed)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but this can also be done quite conveniently with `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (revisit of base `rapply()`):

```r
rrapply::rrapply(
  x,                                        ## nested list
  condition = \(x, .xname) .xname != "id",  ## filter condition
  how = "prune"                             ## how to structure result
) |>
  str()

#> List of 2
#>  $ a:List of 1
#>   ..$ from: chr "me"
#>  $ b:List of 1
#>   ..$ comment:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ message: chr "blabla"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ message: chr "humbug"
```