# Assigning objects to a nested list using different object types in R

Tags: r, list, object, nested, typeof

I want to assign a character vector to a nested list in R. However, my character vector is not assigned to the desired level of the nested list (see Test_List_1).

I tried to change the type of the object to a data.frame and this approach works (see Test_List_2).

How can I recreate the result given by the data.frame only using a character vector?

```
Test_List_1 <- list()
Test_List_1[["String_a"]][["String_b"]][["String_c"]] <- c("Test")
Test_List_1

Test_List_2 <- list()
Test_List_2[["String_a"]][["String_b"]][["String_c"]] <- data.frame("Test")
Test_List_2
```

Comment: Can you actually show the output of *Test_List_#*? Since first is an atomic vector and data  frames are lists of atomic vectors, outputs would differ. So if issue is why `[[#]]` does not appear, it is because `lists != vectors`. But both should be at same level.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I understood, both are not at the same level. I checked one function (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432863/determine-level-of-nesting-in-r) to extract the depth of the lists and got different numbers. 

This is especially problematic if I want to assign two different object types multiple times to the same level of a list. It always results in the error message "subscript out of bounds".